# How to get and set simple maths function in android?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I was building a simple e-Commerce android app. and I want to fetch a discount percentage from the given Actual and Deal price.

Here is my code: (Model Class)

```
String actual_price;
 String deal_price;

 public NotificationModel(String actual_price, String deal_price) {
        this.actual_price = actual_price;
        this.deal_price = deal_price;
    }

public String getActual_price() {
        return actual_price;
    }

    public void setActual_price(String actual_price) {
        this.actual_price = actual_price;
    }

    public String getDeal_price() {
        return deal_price;
    }

    public void setDeal_price(String deal_price) {
        this.deal_price = deal_price;
    }
```

Adapter Class:

```
public TextView actual_price;
        public TextView deal_price;
        public TextView discount_percent;


 actual_price = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.just_in_actual_price);
            deal_price = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.just_in_deal_price);
            discount_percent = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.apv_discount);

 if (TextUtils.isEmpty(notifications.get(position).getActual_price())) {
            holder.actual_price.setText("Not Available");
        } else {
            holder.actual_price.setText("₹" + notifications.get(position).getActual_price());
        }

        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(notifications.get(position).getDeal_price())) {
            holder.deal_price.setText("Not Available");
        } else {
            holder.deal_price.setText("₹" + notifications.get(position).getDeal_price());
        }
```

Not understanding what code to write for getting a discounted percentage. and set it into a discount_percent variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to know how to calculate the discounted percentage, it can be calculated as follows.

> Subtract sale price from original price to determine the discount amount. Next, divide the discount amount by original price. Convert this decimal amount into a percentage. This percent is the discount rate. For an example, a lamp shows a discount price of $30 with an original price of $50. $50 - $30 = $20 20 / 50 = 0.40 0.40 = 40%

Or if you are not sure about where to put the code and what to write over there, you can try this. Have a method in your NotificationModel class which would calculate and return you the discounted percentage. And then you can call that from your adapter like as follows.

> discount_percent.setText(notifications.get(position).discountPercentage());

Your discountPercentage method can be like the one below.

```
    public String discountPercentage() {
        int actualPrice, dealPrice;
        try {
            actualPrice = Integer.parseInt(actual_price);
            dealPrice = Integer.parseInt(deal_price);
        } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
            return "Not Available";
        }

        int discount = actualPrice - dealPrice;
        float discountPercentage = ( (float) discount / actualPrice ) * 100;
        return String.format("%.02f", discountPercentage) + "%";
    }
```

PS :- I have parsed the actual_price and deal_price as Integers assuming they will be so. If they could be float then you may need to parse them as float.